# MySQL Insert 1064 Error, what is wrong with the syntax?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '829-8588, 'magna@Donecnon.com', 'tempus mauris erat eget ipsum. Suspendisse sagi' at line 1
SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO `rrm17b`.`member` (`mem_id`, `mem_fname`, `mem_lname`, `mem_street`,
`mem_city`, `mem_state`, `mem_zip`, `mem_phone`, `mem_email`, `mem_notes`) 
VALUES (1, 'Eric', 'Prince', '946-6616 Turpis Street', 'Bundaberg',
'Queensland', 33906, (215) 829-8588, 'magna@Donecnon.com',
'tempus mauris erat eget ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis. Nullam vitae diam.')
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 44 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: `(215) 829-8588`: doesn't it need quotes, like `'(215) 829-8588'`?

Comment: It sure does...

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the quotes for `(215) 829-8588`. Since it includes `()`, it will have to be mentioned in quotes to be considered as single string

Answer (score 0):

Your query input is in the wrong format.
When you type in (215) 829-8588 , the formatting looks as though you have closed the brackets !, hence the error.

try changing the data type of 'mem_phone' to VARCHAR() then input the values in the form of a string.

```
INSERT INTO rrm17b.member (mem_id, 
                           mem_fname, 
                           mem_lname, 
                           mem_street, 
                           mem_city, 
                           mem_state, 
                           mem_zip, 
                           mem_phone, 
                           mem_email, 
                           mem_notes) 

VALUES (1, 
        'Eric', 
        'Prince', 
        '946-6616 Turpis Street', 
        'Bundaberg', 
        'Queensland', 
        33906,
        '(215) 829-8588', 
        'magna@Donecnon.com', 
        'tempus mauris erat eget ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis. Nullam vitae diam.')
```

Comment: thank you, that was the issue, i just changed the format of the data rather than change the data type